# JSON Post to a url

Tags: json

I need to start with a new project where I need to get data from firebase.  The programmer for the firebase app wants to post the data to me in JSON to a url.  I have experience in PHP but I have no idea how to create this url to where he must post.  Can someone please point me in the direction to go?  Must I create a page on my website or what must I do here?

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should start looking at creating a rest api on a server (I havent worked with php so dont know the best practices there but got [this](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2017/02/create-simple-rest-api-in-php.html%20https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start) when i googled)

The rest api can then handle the post request and then save the data into firebase.